# Is there any way to restrict marklogic search on specific version of the document

Tags: marklogic

I store managed documents into a specific collection in marklogic (through **dls:document-update** and **dls:document-checkin** API). I want search to include only current version documents. Is there any way to do it using search:search API? If not any other suggestions? I know one option is to push old versions into different collection and current version into different. Search only on collection with current version. For some reasons I don want to do this. Are there any other ways of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function http://docs.marklogic.com/dls:documents-query "returns a query that matches the latest versions of the managed documents in the database." That sounds like what you want. To use it with `search:search` you would add the output from the function as an `additional-query` option: http://docs.marklogic.com/search:search?q=search:search#opt-additional-query

DLS supplies a couple of similar options too: you can use http://docs.marklogic.com/dls:document-version-query to match a specific version number, or http://docs.marklogic.com/dls:as-of-query to match documents at a specific time. If you specify the time as now, that should match the latest versions. But `dls:documents-query` should be the most efficient way.

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick response. This is exactly what I was looking for. I have always got right answer from you thank you again for that..