# Document versioning with MarkLogic REST API

Tags: rest, marklogic

We're currently using MarkLogic's dls functions to handle document versioning, and are trying to switch over to use the REST API. The `document` endpoint doesn't use versioning by default, and I can't figure out a way to get it to. I'm referring to the dls functions for keeping multiple document versions, btw, not the new "content versioning" the REST API documentation mentions. In fact, the only reference to document versions in the REST API docs seems to be a line saying that content versioning isn't the same thing.

The only solution we've been able to come up with is to write a custom endpoint that duplicates everything the existing `document` endpoint's `PUT` does, plus document management. I'd rather avoid that if possible, especially when looking at MarkLogic 7's partial document updates. We're using MarkLogic 6 now, if it matters, but it doesn't look like 7 has any new features related to this.

Is there a way to do this using MarkLogic's existing endpoints?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, MarkLogic 7 added content versioning to make refreshing of caches easier. And unfortunately, the DLS library hasn't been integrated into the REST api so far. You can file a feature request at support if you like.

In the mean time, the best suggestion I can give is use a separate route to do document updates using DLS (your current route or a limited custom endpoint that only supports the DLS functions you need for doc updates), and do anything else (as far as possible) using the existing REST api. You can look at this other stackoverflow question to see how to limit searches to the latest doc versions:

[Marklogic REST API search for latest document version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029650/marklogic-rest-api-search-for-latest-document-version)

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

You can write a REST API extension that automates the DLS operations. See http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions. You will largely end up duplicating a lot of the same things, but this will plug into the existing endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

A member of MarkLogic has put together a REST extension to provide better DLS support in the REST-api. Hopefully that makes working with DLS over the MarkLogic REST-api a lot easier:

https://github.com/sanjuthomas/marklogic-dls-rest-extension

HTH!